# OAuth2 using identity not working in Chrome Extension when deployed in webstore

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, chrome-web-store

I am working on a chrome extension which requires oauth2 authorization using "identity" API.

I was successful in authorization when the extension was on my local machine. If I am not logged in chrome, then it asked me to first login to chrome and then the interactive google authorization.

But when I deployed the extension in webstore and authorizing, it is always asking me to Sign in to chrome despite I am already signed in. Even though I am signing in again, it is not showing any further interactive authorization screens.

I have also updated the client id in the webstore extension as per the new extension id generated.
What can be the possible reason? Please help.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You may try the workaround in these threads: [Chrome keeps asking to sign in and re-authenticate every time at start up](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/3ame5l/chrome_keeps_asking_to_sign_in_and_reauthenticate/?st=j95lsv1l&sh=0fbdae85) and [always asking to sign in every time I open the chrome](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/GlPnZRqKQLs). Tryto delete the user folder in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome`. Type this in your browser
`C:\Users\Yourusername\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` and delete the `Web Data`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by adding the public key in the field `"key"` in my `manifest.json`. You can get the public key value from Webstore dashboard.

- Simply go to webstore and click on "**More info**" of your deployed extension.
- Copy the public key and paste it in the `manifest.json` file.

Note: There is no need to add the `"key"` in the local instance but I needed it in the production instance.